# Facebook comments on multiple site

Tags: php, facebook, comments, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

I have 2 version of my site. They are m.example.com and example.com. So I added facebook comment plugin to both of them, but if user writes comment one of them, this comment will not seen in another.

I write some comments on example.com. So I want to see these comments also in m.example.com. What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s a different URL. Try using `example.com` in the `data-href` parameter even on the mobile version:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Comment: Let me try this !

Comment: Great, I used `str_replace` to remove "m" from data-href.